# From a numeric value to zero: a column-wise fill with a linear series

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to fill values from those in 2010 until those in 2021 (zero), under a linear series. Something like this (e.g. In excel, this is Fill > Series in row > type > linear), but I am moving to R 100%:

```
test1:
item   2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021
A     0.808                                                      0
B     0.725                                                      0
C     0.113                                                      0
D     0.158                                                      0
```

Idea I have been exploring:

-select column item and 2010

-mutate a column with years, mutate(across())

-here I do no know how to reach zero after a number of years

-spread based on the years to have them as columns

Also, I have tried this:

```
y <- test1$"2010"
x <- test1$"2021"
predict(lm(y ~ x), list(x = test1[,c("2011":"2020")]))
```

but no success so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `apply` across rows (`MARGIN = 1`) and `seq` with the `length.out` argument to evenly scale down from the value in 2011 to 0 (in 2021):

```
# identify columns you want to sequence
tofrom <- 2:13

df[,tofrom] <- t(apply(df, MARGIN = 1, 
                     function(x) seq(x[tofrom[1]], x[tofrom[length(tofrom)]], 
                                     length.out = length(tofrom))))
```

Output:

```
  item X2010     X2011      X2012      X2013      X2014      X2015      X2016      X2017      X2018      X2019      X2020 X2021
1    A 0.808 0.7345455 0.66109091 0.58763636 0.51418182 0.44072727 0.36727273 0.29381818 0.22036364 0.14690909 0.07345455     0
2    B 0.725 0.6590909 0.59318182 0.52727273 0.46136364 0.39545455 0.32954545 0.26363636 0.19772727 0.13181818 0.06590909     0
3    C 0.113 0.1027273 0.09245455 0.08218182 0.07190909 0.06163636 0.05136364 0.04109091 0.03081818 0.02054545 0.01027273     0
4    D 0.158 0.1436364 0.12927273 0.11490909 0.10054545 0.08618182 0.07181818 0.05745455 0.04309091 0.02872727 0.01436364     0
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "item   2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 
A     0.808 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 0
B     0.725 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 0
C     0.113 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 0
D     0.158 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 0", h = TRUE)
```

This gives you near identical values as to what you'd find in excel using fill > series > linear:

[image]

Comment: I applied the code in my actual task and I got this error: `Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :   error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': 'from' must be a finite number In addition: Warning message:
In seq.default(x[2], 0, length.out = 29) : NAs introduced by coercion`

my code: `test1[,4:29] <- t(apply(test1, MARGIN = 1, 
                     function(x) seq(x[2], 0, length.out = 29)))`

I have had care of structure matches with yours.

Comment: Your `length.out` shouldn't be 29 (there are only 26 columns between columns 4 and 29). Try the modified code I just edited, which is a bit more flexible. Good luck!